# Cacheable with suspend function

Tags: spring, ehcache, kotlin-coroutines

I am trying to write cacheable suspend function, I think it does not work correctly.
I am having:

```
@Cacheable("product-image")
suspend fun getProductImage(productId: String): String {
    return productRetriever.getProductImage(productId).awaitSingle()
}
```

It doesn't seem to cache information. Class is correctly wired.
Following code seems to work but it produces Mono instead of String

```
@Cacheable("product-image")
suspend fun getProductImage(productId: String): Mono<String> {
    return productRetriever.getProductImage(productId).cache()
}
```